# jQuery ui date picker multiple class for multiple group of date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have been using JQuery UI Datepicker.
I need to color some dates. So I followed [this](http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/highlight-particular-dates-jquery-ui-datepicker/) and it worked great for the older version.

But I cannot find out how can I have multiple groups of date and assign each group a CSS class for styling.

For Older version this is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // An array of dates
    var eventDates = {};
    eventDates[ new Date( '08-23-2018' )] = new Date( '08-23-2018' );
    eventDates[ new Date( '08-25-2018' )] = new Date( '08-25-2018' );

    // datepicker
    jQuery('#calendar').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function( date ) {

            var highlight = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', date);
            if( highlight ) {
                 return [true, "event", highlight];
            } else {
                 return [true, '', ''];
            }
         }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is for new version:

```
  <script>

  $(function() {

  //disabled date
  var array = ["08-22-2018","08-25-2018"];

$("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  minDate: "+0d",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("input[name='bookingdate']").val(dateText);
    },
    //disabled date
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', date);

        return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
    }
    });
  });

  </script>
```

Comment: Can you show your code so that we can see your problem? Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have added the codes. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Older version" and "New Version". Are you talking about the version of DatePicker or your code?

Looking at the code what I can understand is you want to disable selection of couple of dates defined in `array` and also highlight those dates as disabled.

The highlighting is not working because you are only returning a single value from `beforeShowDay` function as:

```
return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
```

Instead you need to return something like:

```
if(array.indexOf(string) == -1) {
    return [ false, 'cssClassForHighlighting', 'This date is disabled because XYZ reason']
} else {
    return [true, '', ''];
}
```

Refer documentation of `beforeShowDay` http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

Note: the problem that you have described in your post does not match the title of this post. So change the title to match your requirement described in post.